# Regularization choices and problems in effective Lagrangian (Hamiltonian) derivation

Tags: lagrangian-formalism, hamiltonian, interactions, effective-field-theory

I am trying to derive the explicit form of the effective interaction Lagrangian (Hamiltonian) for fermions interacting via a scalar particle (Yukawa's potential). For that, I am using the Lagrangian

$$ \mathcal{L} = \mathcal{L}_\psi + \mathcal{L}_{\phi} - g \bar{\psi}\psi \phi $$

where $\mathcal{L}_\psi$ is the Dirac Lagrangian and $\mathcal{L}_\phi$ is the Klein-Gordon Lagrangian. In order to find the effective interaction Lagrangian, I am taking the generating functional $Z$ and integrating out  the field $\phi$.  For this task I am using, from Lancaster & Blundell (Quantum Field Theory for the Gifted Amateur - eq. (24.17))

$$ \int \mathcal{D}\phi \exp \big[- \frac{1}{2} \int d^4x \phi(x)\hat{A}\phi(x) + b(x)\phi(x) \big] = \mathcal{C}\exp \Big[ \frac{1}{2} \int d^4x\,d^4y \, b(x)G(x,y)b(y) \Big]  $$

with $b(x) = -g \bar{\psi}(x)\psi(x)$, $ G(x,y)\equiv \hat{A}^{-1}$ and $\hat{A}= i(\square + m^2)$. At this point I found

$$ G(x,y) = -i \int \frac{d^4 k}{(2 \pi)^4} \frac{e^{ik (x-y)}}{k^2- m^2}. $$

With this result, I am considering that the effective  interaction Lagrangian $\mathcal{L}_I$ is
$$ \mathcal{L}_I(x) =  \frac{g^2}{2} \int d^4 y  \bar{\psi}(x)\psi(x) \Bigg(\int \frac{d^4 k}{(2 \pi)^4} \frac{e^{ik (x-y)}}{k^2- m^2}\Bigg)\bar{\psi}(y)\psi(y) .$$

I am following the $+ i \epsilon$ prescription in order to compute integrals over $k$. In the book  Quantum Field Theory: From Operators to Path Integrals (Huang - pages 28-29) we have

$$\Delta_F(x-y) =\int \frac{d^4 k}{(2 \pi)^4} \frac{e^{ik (x-y)}}{k^2- m^2 + i \epsilon}  = \begin{cases}   \frac{m}{8 \pi \sqrt{s}}H_1^{(1)}(m \sqrt{s}), & \text{if $s = (x_0 - y_0)^2 - (\vec{x} - \vec{y})^2 > 0$} \\
\frac{-i m}{4 \pi^2 \sqrt{-s}}K_1(m \sqrt{-s}) , & \text{if $s = (x_0 - y_0)^2 - (\vec{x} - \vec{y})^2 < 0$}     \end{cases},  $$

where $H_1^{(1)}$ and $K_1$ are the Hankel and Modified Bessel functions, respectively.

**Here is the problem:** I want to find the interaction Hamiltonian $H_I (x_0)$  by doing

$$H_I (x_0) =  - \int d^3x \mathcal{L}_I(x),$$

but how  can it be possible, once both results of $\Delta_F$ are complex and  it seems  not  to be hermitian? Is the regularization choice the problem? I am not finding the inconsistency.